# how can i check two columns while inserting values?

Tags: mysql

I have one table with following columns

```
Id fksur_id name email
```

I want to do like this..and it is fine.

```
fksur_id email
2        abc@y.com
2        xyz@y.com
```

this is not ok

```
fksur_id email
2        abc@y.com
2        abc@y.com
```

I would like to know how shall i have to restrict if same email address is being inserted along with same fksur_id. here i want to have duplicate fksur_id with different email or duplicate email with different fksur_id. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not [restrict the column itself as unique](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html)?

Comment: That depends on if the email can be duplicated with a different fksur_id.

Comment: well then you add the constraint on 2 cols...

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer.. if I restrict each as unique it will be a problem.... here it is ok with duplicated email with different fksur_id or it is ok with duplicated fksur_id with different email.

Scott Helme, yeah you're right email can be duplicated with different fksur_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do a SELECT, see if it returns any results and if not, then perform the INSERT?

Comment: You could also force the column to be unique but that depends if you can duplicate the email with a different fksur_id value.

Comment: yes I want to duplicate email with different fksur_id..do you have any idea how can i do that ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE email = '$email' If this returns 0 results then the email does not exist, insert new one. If it does return a result, compare the fksur_id, if they match don't insert, if they don't match, do your insert statement for new entry.

Comment: @ScottHelme Why not search on both email _and_ fksur_id? Zero results would mean it's ok for the insert without a second comparison. `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE email = '$email' AND fksur_id = '$fksur_id'`

Comment: Select and then perform insert. This is a form of check then act. What kind of locking are you using to ensure that no one enters the data in between?? Data integrity features (in this case uniqueness) is best managed by DB so let DB do its work.

Answer (score 4):

Create a unique key using columns fksur_id and email

Comment: alter table tableName add constraint constraintName UNIQUE (fksur_id , email);

Comment: Acutally here i want to have duplicate fksur_id with different email or duplicate email with different fksur_id.

Answer (score 2):

here is [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97566)

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY(FKSUR_ID, EMAIL);
```

If a primary key already exists then you want to do this

```
 ALTER TABLE table_Name ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINTNAME UNIQUE (FKSUR_ID, EMAIL);
```

Comment: You've made it even worse, if an ID is present, you should add a [UNIQUE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) constraint, not a `PRIMARY KEY`, which is a totally seperate thing

Answer (score 1):

Use Unique Index with 2 columns in.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html